# Clearing Byte variable's value that contains a picture

Tags: vb.net

I have a byte variable that stores picture.  How to clear the value of this variable.#

Thanks

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry if i could not make it clear.  I mean after saving record, I am clearing all variables (vrName="" i.e String) but for vrPic i can't do this.  It returns an error

Comment: There is no point in doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the byte array to Nothing?

```
Dim picBytes As Byte()
picBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\temp\test.bmp")
' Do some thing with the bytes
picBytes = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is:

```
Array.Clear(arrayName, arrayName.GetLowerBound(0), arrayName.Length)
```